# not able to change color of link on click

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have menu in right side of page , all the links in menu is orange color. When I hover any of the link it goes to black. But what I want is until I click on any other link it should remain active in black color so that everyone knows the page which is opened belongs to that link.
It might be a silly question but I am not able to do it. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code :

JavaScript function :

```
@section JavaScript{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#allapps a').click(function () {
        $('#allapps a').removeClass('selected'); // remove selected from any other item first
        (this).addClass('selected'); //add selected to the one just clicked.
    });
 </script>
}
```

link :

```
<a id="allapps" class="allapps" href="@Url.Action("CategoryType", "Marketplace", new { @id = 1 })"><h3 class="allapps grid_2 alpha">Legal </h3><p class="grid_1 omega calculate" > @ViewBag.legal</p><br /><br /></a>
```

css:

```
.allapps
{
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12px;
color:#C55000;
padding-left:20px;
font-weight:bold;
}

a.allapps :link {
   color: Black;
}

a.allapps :visited {
 color:Black;}

a.allapps :hover {
 color:Black;}

a.allapps :active {
  color:Black; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the $ or jQuery

*Change*

```
(this).addClass('selected');
```

*To*

```
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

Comment: I tried ,but still it change to orange as soon as i click on link

Answer (score 0):

In your JQuery 
Why you use both the ID name and Tag Name....?

```
$('#allapps a').click(function () {
```

Can you try like below... may be it will help you..

```
$('#allapps').click(function () {
        $('#allapps').removeClass('selected'); // remove selected from any other item first
        $(this).addClass('selected'); //add selected to the one just clicked.
    });
```

Also i didn't find `.selected` Class in your CSS...

Try to add it

```
.selected{
 color:Black;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $(function(){
     var url = window.location.href;
     var page = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
     $('a[href$="'+page+'"]').addClass('selected');

     $('#allapps a').click(function () {
        $('#allapps a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
     });
  });
```

What seems that you want `to highlight the link` but `when clicked on it page get refreshed` and `applied class gets removed.`

Comment: yes my whole page get refreshed i tries above but still nothing happen

Comment: `var page = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);` this line depends on your url structure. if you could paste the generated html of links then i could easily help with this.